# Labelling lines with multiple fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, qgis-2

I need on the linear value such an effect as on the point. That is, that the three labels should be next to each other and decrease and grow dynamically. On the screenshots you can see that this is not the case. Please note the scale. How can a function solve this?

[image]

[image]

I am working on the qgis version: 2.18.18
I will send more screenshot to describe my problem[image] the three labels must be with you and must be dynamic.
like(look at scale)[image]
[image]

now an example with a linear layer:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired output via the [Rule-based labeling](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#rule-based-labeling), see image below

[image: result1]

If the same styles should be applied, simply use the concatenation i.e. `"Field1" || '-' || "Field2"`

[image: result2]

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Can you be more explicit: how exactly?

Comment: As I mentioned, it works on qgis version 2.18.28 and when it gives 3 defined labels per point, they are next to each other and do not overlap. However, when it adds the same to the line values as you zoom in and out, these three different labels overlap and change order (the display order should be: A; G; 2, see picture). I need a solution so that the labels are in the order: A; G; 3 and with the change of the map scale display they do not overlap. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you use QGIS 2?

Comment: it does not depend on me, but on the company

Comment: You / your company should definitifely stick to the current QGIS version! QGIS 2.18 is out of support for almost 4 years (!) now and as you see, the new versions released since then come with tons and tons of new features. If using software, you have to update from time to time to be productive.